# server unaccessable from outside my local internet

Tags: c#, server, client

hey I am trying to make an app that connects to the server and gets some info from it.
the app works wonderfully... from my own network only.
how can I make it to work on networks that are not my own localhost.

code to server:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace GatherServer
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int connections = 0, team1 = 0, team2 = 0;
        static TcpListener myList = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9874);
        static void Listeners()
        {
            Socket socketForClient = myList.AcceptSocket();
            if(socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                connections++;
                Console.WriteLine("Client Connected: " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint);
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    string newString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    if (newString == "exit")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Player has left the game: "+socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(connections.ToString());
                        streamWriter.Flush();
                        if (connections == 12)
                        {
                            Random rnd = new Random();
                            int team = rnd.Next(1, 3); // creates a number between 1 and 2
                            if(team == 1)
                            {
                                if (team1 < 6)
                                {
                                    team1++;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Player " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 1");
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team1");
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Player " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 2");
                                    team2++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team2");
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                            if(team == 2)
                            {
                                if (team2 < 6)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Player " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 2");
                                    team2++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team2");
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Player " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " assigned to Team 1");
                                    team1++;
                                    streamWriter.WriteLine("team1");
                                    streamWriter.Flush();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }  
                    }
                }
                connections--;
                streamWriter.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                networkStream.Close();
                socketForClient.Close();
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            myList.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Sever is up and running...");

            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
                newThread.Start();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I opened the port im using in my router, and I disabled my firewall.. 
help?

Comment: First make sure you can ping server from cmd.exe.  If you can't ping then the address is blocked.  Try ping from using both IP address and computer name.   Sometimes one will work and not the other.  I can help solve ping issues.  Try ping from both client and server.  Again sometime one direction works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Can you describe your network?  Usually home routers aren't enabled to have two computer in the house talk directly to each other.  You may need to modify routers settings.